# Customizing queryCatalog script in Plone or using reversed chronological order by default

Tags: plone

I have been asked to help in tweaking an Intranet  done with Plone 4.0.5; one of the requirements is to always (by default) use the reversed chronological order in folder's listings.

I haven't touch Plone since it was at version 2.5; so lots have changed.

Is there any simple parameter/configuration to accomplish this?

Failing that. I have tracked the fetching of the showed items to queryCatalog script inside portal_skins/plone_scripts.

I have customized this script TTW. Later I plan to customize this by means of whatever you recommend (an adapter?, a ZCML? I have yet to study that stuff). What are the best practices these days?

If I have set the `'sort_on'` and `'sort_order'` keys by hand everything seems to behave as I'd want. But if I use the `setdefault` method of dicts, then nothing happens, so it seems that an order has been requested.

How can I log inside a script customized TTW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of patching the catalog (which might change sort order in navigation or other places where you don't want/need it) you could

- customize the folder-views you're using (eg folder_summary_view)
  this might help: http://keeshink.blogspot.co.at/2009/06/how-to-change-plones-default-folder.html
- use collections to display items contained in the folder (only a good idea if you need the reverse order just in some folders)
- or use one of these addons http://plone.org/products/collective.sortmyfolder
  or http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wildcard.foldercontents

Comment: On a custom install wildcard.foldercontents does not work as expected. Besides documentation is rather poor. I will have to take a look at the code. But first, going to test collective.sortmyfolder.

Comment: The blog recommends essentially what I've done. And yes, you're right going the "collection" way does not scale for my case since I was asked for a default ordering in all folders, current and those to come.

Comment: I've being thinking in going other way: making a content rule that changes the order of the item in the parent folder... But this is just an idea. I don't know if my client would be affected by that.

Comment: collective.sortmyfolder does not work either. It seems the folder_position does not work anymore (tested on Plone 4.2.1, since I would like to update; I will test on Plone 4.0.5)

Answer (score 0):

For logging:

```
context.plone_log('My script', 'My message')
```

You seem to be on the right track otherwise.

Comment: Thanks this allows me to peek at what's happening.